# Animations not smooth on new devices

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm trying to write a simple animation of setting one ImageView alpha from 0 to 1 and the other from 1 to 0:

```
AlphaAnimation animationOutside = new AlphaAnimation(1,0);
AlphaAnimation animationInside = new AlphaAnimation(0,1);

animationOutside.setDuration(1000);
animationInside.setDuration(1000);

animationInside.setFillAfter(true);
animationOutside.setFillAfter(true);

oldCharacter.startAnimation(animationOutside);
newCharacter.startAnimation(animationInside);
```

This looks great on Samsung Galaxy 1 but for some reason on a Nexus 5 the animation looks really bad and looks like it's missing a lot of frames.

I already tried to add
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of the difference of the manufacturer. Animation (you can include audio and video) are hardware dependent. Normally, some animation may not work "properly" on some devices.

Comment: I just find it wired that there is no way to change the alpha (or move) two images smoothly on new phones.

Comment: (Just as an example) Having two new phones doesn't mean that they can run the same application / images / animation smoothly. They will have differences. Manufacturers tend to have the mindset of being unique in something that makes them different from other brand new phones. They're not like PCs. I may be wrong though.